# Why do I get the wrong result of the addition of unsigned integers using infinite for loop?

Tags: c

Here is my code (about an infinite loop) from my book, but when I run the program and add i.e. `5` and `5`, and I type `1` to exit, I get `12`.

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int num;
    unsigned long sum;

    for ( ; ; )
    {
        printf("Enter a number from 2-65535 or enter 1 to end a program.\n");
        scanf("%u", &num);
        if(num == 1)
            break;
        else
            sum+=num;

    }
    printf("Total sum: %lu.\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong and to fix the error ?

Comment: `unsigned long sum =0`; initialize to zero

Comment: You should initialize `sum` to zero before enter the `for()` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not initialized the variable `sum`. Its value is **indeterminate**.

#### 6.7.9 Initialization:

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate.

Initialize it to `0`

```
unsigned long sum = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

`sum` is not initialized. It has *indeterminate* value.

Answer (score 2):

You should initialise `sum` at the top of your program. It could be anything!